# How to set the default value of an Item.Field() in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website which does not display the same data from page to page. I'd like my spider to return a default value for each attribute it could not scrape. I know that this could be done in the item declaration like this :

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
     myfield = scrapy.Field(default='NULL')
```

However, this method seems not to work anymore (I'm using Scrapy 1.3.0). If I try to export this particular field when the value has not been found I got :

```
KeyError: 'myfield'
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Support of default values for fields was removed from Scrapy about 4 years ago (I'm just curious about which version have you used previously). According to Pablo Hoffman recommended way is to populate items with default values through pipeline:

```
class DefaultValuesPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item.setdefault('field1', 'value1')
        item.setdefault('field2', 'value2')
        # ...
        return item
```

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scrapy-users/-v1p5W41VDQ/0W9SIB07iDIJ

However you can just extend default Field class to implement desired behavior.

Comment: I knew it was removed, but I never had to deal with inconsistent data streams before so I never really paid attention. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: is there a reason for setting default to, say, 'NULL' as the OP has suggested? wouldn't an empty field object/value `== NULL`?

Comment: Scrapy can use DataClasses which can be assigned default values. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627526/2650325)

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I've done to solve this issue. As mentioned by @mizhgun, you can set up default values using a pipeline. If you need to iterate over the fields, use the `field` argument rather than the built-in `item.items()` method since `items()` only gives the populated fields back :

```
class DefaultValuesPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        for field in item.fields:
            item.setdefault(field, 'NULL')

    return item
```

Comment: sure, this is an easy way to set all of the defaults, but how do you set the actual fields which are looped through?

Comment: in items.py file?

Comment: is there a reason for setting default to, say, 'NULL' as the OP has suggested? wouldn't an empty field object/value `== NULL`?