# Scrapy How can I populate empty items with itemloader?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape an e-commerce website. My goal is to get sellers' information.

I made my code simpler than the actual code

When my spider visited a page that didn't have a seller's data, my item fields `'company'` and `'owner'` were populated with None.
And yes, that's okay that my fields are populated with None. But my problem is that my fields are just gone!

```
# My spider
class GmarketSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gmarket'
    allowed_domains = ['gmarket.co.kr']
    start_urls = ['http://www.gmarket.co.kr/']
    rules = (
        Rule(callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        loader = GmarketLoader(item=GmarketItem(), response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('company', '//something')
        loader.add_xpath('owner', '//something')
        return loader.load_item()


# My item
class GmarketItem(scrapy.Item):
    company = scrapy.Field()
    owner = scrapy.Field()



# My loader
class GmarketLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = Identity()
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()


# My pipeline
class InvalidPagePipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['owner'] is None: # This line gives me an error
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            return item
```

Please see my pipeline code. I checked the item['owner']'s value whether the page is valid or not. If the page is invalid, then I expected the item['owner'] was populated with None. But it gives me an error because the 'owner' key is completely gone...

This is the error message

```
2019-11-05 20:22:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'market': ['Gmarket'],
 'url': ['https://sslmember2.gmarket.co.kr/FindPW/FindPW?targetUrl=http%3a%2f%2fmyg.gmarket.co.kr%2f']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python projects\sellerinfoscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Python Projects\SellerInfoScraper\sellerInfo\sellerInfo\pipelines.py", line 14, in process_item
    if item['owner'] is None:
  File "d:\python projects\sellerinfoscraper\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'owner'
```

It said `KeyError: 'owner'`

How can I populate item fields with None value using ItemLoader?
I know I can solve this problem without using ItemLoader but I don't want to use this feature.

Comment: [How to set the default value of an Item.Field() in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998498/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-an-item-field-in-scrapy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the default value of an Item.Field() in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998498/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-an-item-field-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

By default scrapy's ItemLoader discards any `None` fields

To fix this you need to make sure the loader will use some other value like an empty string: `""`

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose

def default_action(value):
    return value or ''

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = Compose(default_action)
```

For instance, it'll behave like the following:

```
>>> l = MyLoader()
>>> l.add_value('company', None)
>>> l.load_item()
{}
>>> l.add_value('company', '')
>>> l.load_item()
{'company': ['']}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it's never works